# Unable to delete files as a root user using RS232 serial cross cable

Tags: files, embedded, startup, readonly

I have a device (CCTV decoder) which was rebooting itself, so can't login using LAN cable. It has RS232 port only, no VGA and keyboard/USB port (Embedded PC).

I connected RS232 cross cable and used Teraterm, I entered to setup mode. Where I can see all files and directories. I can't edit any file/folder being root user. But I can edit through telnet remotely for a normal device. I do not know the reason behind.

Here below is the log, please help me to sort out the problem.

```
~ # ls -l
drwxrwxrwx    2 root     0               0 Jan  1  1970 bin
drwxrwxrwx    2 root     0               0 Nov 12  2003 boot
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     0               0 Feb  7  2007 config
drwxrwxrwx    5 root     0               0 Jan  1  1970 dev
drwxrwxrwx    5 root     0               0 Feb  7  2007 etc
-rw-r--r--    1 root     0         1157024 Jan  1  1970 h264dec_encrypt
drwxrwxrwx    4 root     0               0 Nov 16  2007 lib
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     0              11 Nov 16  2007 linuxrc -> bin/busybox
-rw-r--r--    1 root     0           52707 Jan  1  1970 log
drwxrwxrwx    2 root     0               0 Nov 24  2003 proc
drwxrwxrwx    2 root     0               0 Nov 16  2007 sbin
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     0               0 Nov 16  2007 snmp
-rw-r--r--    1 root     0              23 Jan  1  1970 snmpd.log
drwxrwxrwx    2 root     0               0 Dec 16  2003 tmp
-rw-r--r--    1 root     0              21 Jan  1 00:00 userinfo
drwxrwxrwx    6 root     0               0 Jan  1  1970 usr
drwxrwxr-x    2 root     0               0 Mar 12  2004 var
-rw-r--r--    1 root     0               1 Nov 16  2007 ver
drwxr-xr-x    4 root     0               0 Nov 16  2007 web
~ # 

U-Boot 1.0.0 (Jul 13 2009 - 10:43:14)

CPU:   IBM PowerPC 405EP Rev. B at 199.999 MHz (PLB=99, OPB=49, EBC=33 MHz)
       IIC Boot EEPROM disabled
       PCI async ext clock used, internal PCI arbiter enabled
       16 kB I-Cache 16 kB D-Cache
Board: ### No HW ID - assuming WMIA405EP
I2C:   ready
DRAM:  16 MB
Memory ok!
Boot from Flash
Top of RAM usable for U-Boot at: 01000000
Reserving 194k for U-Boot at: 00fcf000
Reserving 132k for malloc() at: 00fae000
Reserving 112 Bytes for Board Info at: 00fadf90
Reserving 48 Bytes for Global Data at: 00fadf60
Setting up new stack space
Stack Pointer at: 00fadf48
New Stack Pointer is: 00fadf48
Watch dog reset
Copy Global data struct 
Relocate the code
Now running in RAM - U-Boot at: 00fcf000
FLASH: Manufacture id 0
## Unknown FLASH on Bank 0 - Size = 0x00000000 = 0 MB
2 banks config
Bank 1 size 800000
Manufacture id 0
Bank 0 size 0
Resize bank 1 to 800000
 8 MB
env_relocate[217] offset = 0x100f000
env_relocate[235] malloced ENV at 00fae008
default="00:11:22:12:67:20", curr="00:0F:D0:80:01:62".
PCI Autoconfig: Memory region: [80000000-9fffffff]
PCI Autoconfig: Memory region: [a0000000-bfffffff]
PCI Autoconfig: I/O region: [800000-3ffffff]
PCI Scan: Found Bus 0, Device 10, Function 0 Vendor 12d5
PCI Autoconfig: BAR 0, Mem, size=0x8000000, address=0x80000000
PCI Autoconfig: BAR 1, Mem, size=0x1000000, address=0xa0000000
In:    serial
Out:   serial
Err:   serial
KGDB:  kgdb ready
ready
U-Boot relocated to 00fcf000
### main_loop entered: bootdelay=1

### main_loop: bootcmd="bootm 0xF0000000"
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  1  0 
## Booting image at f0000000 ...
   Image Name:   WMIA
   Created:      2009-07-13   2:44:13 UTC
   Image Type:   PowerPC Linux Kernel Image (gzip compressed)
   Data Size:    748316 Bytes = 730.8 kB
   Load Address: 00000000
   Entry Point:  00000000
   Verifying Checksum ... OK
   Uncompressing Kernel Image ... OK
## Current stack ends at 0x00FAD578 => set upper limit to 0x00800000
## cmdline at 0x007FFC00 ... 0x007FFCF2
bd address  = 0x00FADF90
memstart    = 0x00000000
memsize     = 0x01000000
flashstart  = 0xFFFC0000
flashsize   = 0x00800000
flashoffset = 0x0002AF00
sramstart   = 0x00000000
sramsize    = 0x00000000
bootflags   = 0x0000A000
procfreq    = 199.999 MHz
plb_busfreq = 99.999 MHz
pci_busfreq = 24.999 MHz
ethaddr     = 00:0F:D0:80:01:62
IP addr     = 192.168.1.3
baudrate    = 115200 bps
No initrd
## Transferring control to Linux (at address 00000000) ...
Linux version 2.4.20_mvl31-405ep_eval (root@localhost.localdomain) (gcc version 3.2.1 20020930 (MontaVista)) #9 Mon Jul 13 10:43:58 CST 2009
ioremap PCLIO_BASE = 0xe7ffd000
PCI bridge regs before fixup 
 pmm0ma 0xe0000001
 pmm0ma 0x80000000
 pmm0ma 0x80000000
 pmm0ma 0x0
 pmm1ma 0xe0000001
 pmm1ma 0xa0000000
 pmm1ma 0xa0000000
 pmm1ma 0x0
 pmm2ma 0x0
 pmm2ma 0x0
 pmm2ma 0x0
 pmm2ma 0x0
 ptm1ms 0x80000001
 ptm1la 0x0
 ptm2ms 0x0
 ptm2la 0x0
BUS 0, device 0, Function 0 bar 0x00000014 is 0x00000008
BUS 0, device 0, Function 0 bar 0x00000018 is 0x00000008
BUS 0, device 0, Function 0 bar 0x00000018 is 0xc0000008
PCI bridge regs after fixup 
 pmm0ma 0xc0000001
 pmm0ma 0x80000000
 pmm0ma 0x80000000
 pmm0ma 0x0
 pmm1ma 0x0
 pmm1ma 0x0
 pmm1ma 0x0
 pmm1ma 0x0
 pmm2ma 0x0
 pmm2ma 0x0
 pmm2ma 0x0
 pmm2ma 0x0
 ptm1ms 0x1
 ptm1la 0x0
 ptm2ms 0xfff00001
 ptm2la 0xf0800000
Setup DMA channel: 0
Transfer width: 2^0 bytes
Setup DMA channel: 1
Transfer width: 2^0 bytes
Setup DMA channel: 2
Transfer width: 2^0 bytes
Setup DMA channel: 3
Transfer width: 2^0 bytes
ASTRI WMIA405EP Evaluation Board port Version 3
On node 0 totalpages: 4096
zone(0): 4096 pages.
zone(1): 0 pages.
zone(2): 0 pages.
Kernel command line: root=/dev/mtdblock1 ip=192.168.1.3:192.168.1.100:192.168.1.1:255.255.255.0:WMIA405EP_1:eth0: console=ttyS1,115200 mtd_part=kernel,0x00000000,0x000C0000,rfs,0x000C0000,0x00700000,bootloader,0x007C0000,0x00040000 boardname=wmia405epV2 decoder=1
Parsing partition parameter from command line...3 partitions in total.
Console: colour dummy device 80x25
Calibrating delay loop... 199.47 BogoMIPS
Memory: 14392k available (1252k kernel code, 412k data, 96k init, 0k highmem)
Dentry cache hash table entries: 2048 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
Inode cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
Mount-cache hash table entries: 512 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
Buffer-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
Page-cache hash table entries: 4096 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
POSIX conformance testing by UNIFIX
PCI: Probing PCI hardware
idsel 10 pin 1
Linux NET4.0 for Linux 2.4
Based upon Swansea University Computer Society NET3.039
Initializing RT netlink socket
OCP uart ver 1.6.2 init complete
LSP Revision 1
Starting kswapd
Disabling the Out Of Memory Killer
JFFS2 version 2.1. (C) 2001, 2002 Red Hat, Inc., designed by Axis Communications AB.
i2c-core.o: i2c core module version 2.6.2 (20011118)
i2c-dev.o: i2c /dev entries driver module version 2.6.2 (20011118)
i2c-proc.o version 2.6.2 (20011118)
pty: 256 Unix98 ptys configured
Serial driver version 5.05c (2001-07-08) with MANY_PORTS SHARE_IRQ SERIAL_PCI enabled
ttyS00 at 0xef600300 (irq = 0) is a 16550A
ttyS01 at 0xef600400 (irq = 1) is a 16550A
PPC 405 watchdog driver v0.6
IBM gpio driver version 07.25.02
GPIO #0 at 0xc2070700
loop: loaded (max 8 devices)
Reset ethernet interfaces
Reset ethernet interfaces
eth1: Cannot open interface without Link
IBM IIC driver v2.0
ibm-iic0: using fast (400 kHz) mode
physmap flash device: 800000 at f0000000
NO QRY response
cfi_cmdset_0001: Erase suspend on write enabled
Using buffer write method
Creating 3 MTD partitions on "phys_mapped_flash":
0x00000000-0x000c0000 : "kernel"
0x000c0000-0x007c0000 : "rfs"
0x007c0000-0x00800000 : "bootloader"
NET4: Linux TCP/IP 1.0 for NET4.0
IP Protocols: ICMP, UDP, TCP, IGMP
IP: routing cache hash table of 512 buckets, 4Kbytes
TCP: Hash tables configured (established 1024 bind 2048)
eth0: IBM EMAC: link up, 10 Mbps Half Duplex.
eth0: IBM EMAC: MAC 00:0f:d0:80:01:62.
After display status
eth0:$$$$$$$$$$$$$will config mac address
eth0:$$$$$$$$$$$$$config mac address ok
eth0:$$$$$$$$$$$$$will request irq
$$$$$$$$$$$$$request irq ok
eth0:will init rings
will enable mal chan
eth0: IBM EMAC: open completed

IP-Config: Complete:
      device=eth0, addr=192.168.1.3, mask=255.255.255.0, gw=192.168.1.1,
     host=WMIA405EP_1, domain=, nis-domain=(none),
     bootserver=192.168.1.100, rootserver=192.168.1.100, rootpath=
NET4: Unix domain sockets 1.0/SMP for Linux NET4.0.
VFS: Mounted root (jffs2 filesystem) readonly.
Freeing unused kernel memory: 96k init
init started:  BusyBox v1.00-pre8 (2007.11.16-10:05+0000) multi-call binary


BusyBox v1.00-pre8 (2007.11.16-10:05+0000) Built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.


Processing /etc/profile... 
Press CTRL-C to enter shell within 3 sec
KERNEL,wdt_period=15
The timeout was set to 15000000 seconds
The timeout was is 0 seconds
```

*(reboot)*

```
U-Boot 1.0.0 (Jul 13 2009 - 10:43:14)
CPU:   IBM PowerPC 405EP Rev. B at 199.999 MHz (PLB=99, OPB=49, EBC=33 MHz)
       IIC Boot EEPROM disabled
       PCI async ext clock used, internal PCI arbiter enabled
       16 kB I-Cache 16 kB D-Cache
Board: ### No HW ID - assuming WMIA405EP
I2C:   ready
DRAM:  16 MB
Memory ok!
Boot from Flash
Top of RAM usable for U-Boot at: 01000000
Reserving 194k for U-Boot at: 00fcf000
Reserving 132k for malloc() at: 00fae000
Reserving 112 Bytes for Board Info at: 00fadf90
Reserving 48 Bytes for Global Data at: 00fadf60
Setting up new stack space
Stack Pointer at: 00fadf48
New Stack Pointer is: 00fadf48
Watch dog reset
Copy Global data struct 
Relocate the code
Now running in RAM - U-Boot at: 00fcf000
FLASH: Manufacture id 0
## Unknown FLASH on Bank 0 - Size = 0x00000000 = 0 MB
2 banks config
Bank 1 size 800000
Manufacture id 0
Bank 0 size 0
Resize bank 1 to 800000
 8 MB
env_relocate[217] offset = 0x100f000
env_relocate[235] malloced ENV at 00fae008
default="00:11:22:12:67:20", curr="00:0F:D0:80:01:62".
PCI Autoconfig: Memory region: [80000000-9fffffff]
PCI Autoconfig: Memory region: [a0000000-bfffffff]
PCI Autoconfig: I/O region: [800000-3ffffff]
PCI Scan: Found Bus 0, Device 10, Function 0 Vendor 12d5
PCI Autoconfig: BAR 0, Mem, size=0x8000000, address=0x80000000
PCI Autoconfig: BAR 1, Mem, size=0x1000000, address=0xa0000000
In:    serial
Out:   serial
Err:   serial
KGDB:  kgdb ready
ready
U-Boot relocated to 00fcf000
### main_loop entered: bootdelay=1

### main_loop: bootcmd="bootm 0xF0000000"
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  1  0 
=> <INTERRUPT>
=> <INTERRUPT>
=> <INTERRUPT>
=> <INTERRUPT>
=>
```

*(reboot)*

```
U-Boot 1.0.0 (Jul 13 2009 - 10:43:14)
CPU:   IBM PowerPC 405EP Rev. B at 199.999 MHz (PLB=99, OPB=49, EBC=33 MHz)
       IIC Boot EEPROM disabled
       PCI async ext clock used, internal PCI arbiter enabled
       16 kB I-Cache 16 kB D-Cache
Board: ### No HW ID - assuming WMIA405EP
I2C:   ready
DRAM:  16 MB
Memory ok!
Boot from Flash
Top of RAM usable for U-Boot at: 01000000
Reserving 194k for U-Boot at: 00fcf000
Reserving 132k for malloc() at: 00fae000
Reserving 112 Bytes for Board Info at: 00fadf90
Reserving 48 Bytes for Global Data at: 00fadf60
Setting up new stack space
Stack Pointer at: 00fadf48
New Stack Pointer is: 00fadf48
Watch dog reset
Copy Global data struct 
Relocate the code
Now running in RAM - U-Boot at: 00fcf000
FLASH: Manufacture id 0
## Unknown FLASH on Bank 0 - Size = 0x00000000 = 0 MB
2 banks config
Bank 1 size 800000
Manufacture id 0
Bank 0 size 0
Resize bank 1 to 800000
 8 MB
env_relocate[217] offset = 0x100f000
env_relocate[235] malloced ENV at 00fae008
default="00:11:22:12:67:20", curr="00:0F:D0:80:01:62".
PCI Autoconfig: Memory region: [80000000-9fffffff]
PCI Autoconfig: Memory region: [a0000000-bfffffff]
PCI Autoconfig: I/O region: [800000-3ffffff]
PCI Scan: Found Bus 0, Device 10, Function 0 Vendor 12d5
PCI Autoconfig: BAR 0, Mem, size=0x8000000, address=0x80000000
PCI Autoconfig: BAR 1, Mem, size=0x1000000, address=0xa0000000
In:    serial
Out:   serial
Err:   serial
KGDB:  kgdb ready
ready
U-Boot relocated to 00fcf000
### main_loop entered: bootdelay=1

### main_loop: bootcmd="bootm 0xF0000000"
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  1  0 
## Booting image at f0000000 ...
   Image Name:   WMIA
   Created:      2009-07-13   2:44:13 UTC
   Image Type:   PowerPC Linux Kernel Image (gzip compressed)
   Data Size:    748316 Bytes = 730.8 kB
   Load Address: 00000000
   Entry Point:  00000000
   Verifying Checksum ... OK
   Uncompressing Kernel Image ... OK
## Current stack ends at 0x00FAD578 => set upper limit to 0x00800000
## cmdline at 0x007FFC00 ... 0x007FFCF2
bd address  = 0x00FADF90
memstart    = 0x00000000
memsize     = 0x01000000
flashstart  = 0xFFFC0000
flashsize   = 0x00800000
flashoffset = 0x0002AF00
sramstart   = 0x00000000
sramsize    = 0x00000000
bootflags   = 0x0000A000
procfreq    = 199.999 MHz
plb_busfreq = 99.999 MHz
pci_busfreq = 24.999 MHz
ethaddr     = 00:0F:D0:80:01:62
IP addr     = 192.168.1.3
baudrate    = 115200 bps
No initrd
## Transferring control to Linux (at address 00000000) ...
Linux version 2.4.20_mvl31-405ep_eval (root@localhost.localdomain) (gcc version 3.2.1 20020930 (MontaVista)) #9 Mon Jul 13 10:43:58 CST 2009
ioremap PCLIO_BASE = 0xe7ffd000
PCI bridge regs before fixup 
 pmm0ma 0xe0000001
 pmm0ma 0x80000000
 pmm0ma 0x80000000
 pmm0ma 0x0
 pmm1ma 0xe0000001
 pmm1ma 0xa0000000
 pmm1ma 0xa0000000
 pmm1ma 0x0
 pmm2ma 0x0
 pmm2ma 0x0
 pmm2ma 0x0
 pmm2ma 0x0
 ptm1ms 0x80000001
 ptm1la 0x0
 ptm2ms 0x0
 ptm2la 0x0
BUS 0, device 0, Function 0 bar 0x00000014 is 0x00000008
BUS 0, device 0, Function 0 bar 0x00000018 is 0x00000008
BUS 0, device 0, Function 0 bar 0x00000018 is 0xc0000008
PCI bridge regs after fixup 
 pmm0ma 0xc0000001
 pmm0ma 0x80000000
 pmm0ma 0x80000000
 pmm0ma 0x0
 pmm1ma 0x0
 pmm1ma 0x0
 pmm1ma 0x0
 pmm1ma 0x0
 pmm2ma 0x0
 pmm2ma 0x0
 pmm2ma 0x0
 pmm2ma 0x0
 ptm1ms 0x1
 ptm1la 0x0
 ptm2ms 0xfff00001
 ptm2la 0xf0800000
Setup DMA channel: 0
Transfer width: 2^0 bytes
Setup DMA channel: 1
Transfer width: 2^0 bytes
Setup DMA channel: 2
Transfer width: 2^0 bytes
Setup DMA channel: 3
Transfer width: 2^0 bytes
ASTRI WMIA405EP Evaluation Board port Version 3
On node 0 totalpages: 4096
zone(0): 4096 pages.
zone(1): 0 pages.
zone(2): 0 pages.
Kernel command line: root=/dev/mtdblock1 ip=192.168.1.3:192.168.1.100:192.168.1.1:255.255.255.0:WMIA405EP_1:eth0: console=ttyS1,115200 mtd_part=kernel,0x00000000,0x000C0000,rfs,0x000C0000,0x00700000,bootloader,0x007C0000,0x00040000 boardname=wmia405epV2 decoder=1
Parsing partition parameter from command line...3 partitions in total.
Console: colour dummy device 80x25
Calibrating delay loop... 199.47 BogoMIPS
Memory: 14392k available (1252k kernel code, 412k data, 96k init, 0k highmem)
Dentry cache hash table entries: 2048 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
Inode cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
Mount-cache hash table entries: 512 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
Buffer-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
Page-cache hash table entries: 4096 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
POSIX conformance testing by UNIFIX
PCI: Probing PCI hardware
idsel 10 pin 1
Linux NET4.0 for Linux 2.4
Based upon Swansea University Computer Society NET3.039
Initializing RT netlink socket
OCP uart ver 1.6.2 init complete
LSP Revision 1
Starting kswapd
Disabling the Out Of Memory Killer
JFFS2 version 2.1. (C) 2001, 2002 Red Hat, Inc., designed by Axis Communications AB.
i2c-core.o: i2c core module version 2.6.2 (20011118)
i2c-dev.o: i2c /dev entries driver module version 2.6.2 (20011118)
i2c-proc.o version 2.6.2 (20011118)
pty: 256 Unix98 ptys configured
Serial driver version 5.05c (2001-07-08) with MANY_PORTS SHARE_IRQ SERIAL_PCI enabled
ttyS00 at 0xef600300 (irq = 0) is a 16550A
ttyS01 at 0xef600400 (irq = 1) is a 16550A
PPC 405 watchdog driver v0.6
IBM gpio driver version 07.25.02
GPIO #0 at 0xc2070700
loop: loaded (max 8 devices)
Reset ethernet interfaces
Reset ethernet interfaces
eth1: Cannot open interface without Link
IBM IIC driver v2.0
ibm-iic0: using fast (400 kHz) mode
physmap flash device: 800000 at f0000000
NO QRY response
cfi_cmdset_0001: Erase suspend on write enabled
Using buffer write method
Creating 3 MTD partitions on "phys_mapped_flash":
0x00000000-0x000c0000 : "kernel"
0x000c0000-0x007c0000 : "rfs"
0x007c0000-0x00800000 : "bootloader"
NET4: Linux TCP/IP 1.0 for NET4.0
IP Protocols: ICMP, UDP, TCP, IGMP
IP: routing cache hash table of 512 buckets, 4Kbytes
TCP: Hash tables configured (established 1024 bind 2048)
eth0: IBM EMAC: link up, 10 Mbps Half Duplex.
eth0: IBM EMAC: MAC 00:0f:d0:80:01:62.
After display status
eth0:$$$$$$$$$$$$$will config mac address
eth0:$$$$$$$$$$$$$config mac address ok
eth0:$$$$$$$$$$$$$will request irq
$$$$$$$$$$$$$request irq ok
eth0:will init rings
will enable mal chan
eth0: IBM EMAC: open completed
IP-Config: Complete:
      device=eth0, addr=192.168.1.3, mask=255.255.255.0, gw=192.168.1.1,
     host=WMIA405EP_1, domain=, nis-domain=(none),
     bootserver=192.168.1.100, rootserver=192.168.1.100, rootpath=
NET4: Unix domain sockets 1.0/SMP for Linux NET4.0.
VFS: Mounted root (jffs2 filesystem) readonly.
Freeing unused kernel memory: 96k init
init started:  BusyBox v1.00-pre8 (2007.11.16-10:05+0000) multi-call binary


BusyBox v1.00-pre8 (2007.11.16-10:05+0000) Built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

chmod: /etc/profile: Read-only file system

Processing /etc/profile... 
KERNEL,wdt_period=15
The timeout was set to 15000000 seconds
The timeout was is 0 seconds
Press CTRL-C to enter shell within 3 sec
rm: unable to remove `/dev/rts_wtd': Read-only file system
mkfifo failed!
Using /lib/modules/proc_jiffies.o
Using /lib/modules/etimap.o
Loading etimap modules
packetintf:[1]Using packet interface
9600
/etc/profile: 55: cannot create /proc/sys/net/core/rmem_default: Directory nonexistent
/etc/profile: 55: cannot create /proc/sys/net/core/wmem_default: Directory nonexistent
/etc/profile: 55: cannot create /proc/sys/net/core/rmem_max: Directory nonexistent
/etc/profile: 55: cannot create /proc/sys/net/core/wmem_max: Directory nonexistent
Build date Nov 16 2007 18:05:41
RTC enable
Use codec ./h264dec_encrypt
CPU clock speed: 378
MEM clock speed: 126
/var/etidaemon.pid: Read-only file system
ETimap think device 0 has etimap c2891000 1332
etimap_ioctl called one time
Init bsp CORE speed: 378
etimap_ioctl called one time
Init bsp MEM speed: 126
etimap_ioctl called one time
eti_board(0): brd_open(): CPU: Equator Technologies, Inc. BSP-15.
eti_board(0): brd_open(): board: WMIA405EP Version 3/4 (0xf). Use StringRay settings.
No ACK from slave @ addr 0xa4 in iicTx
eti_board(0): WARNING: IIC Send failed while attempting to read EEPROM
No ACK from slave @ addr 0x70 in iicTx
eti_board(0): WARNING: IIC Write to IIC Expander failed. VCXO may be active.
No ACK from slave @ addr 0xa0 in iicTx
sizeof(bsp_argv[0]) = 32
Segmentation fault
/etc/profile: 55: cannot create /proc/etivideo0: Read-only file system
nanowm: opening frontpanel device /dev/ttys0
/etc/last_ch is accessible
Init channel:1
listening :
use setting file: /etc/rts_player.conf'
main: setting_file /etc/rts_player.conf
Openning config file /etc/rts_player.conf
OpenLogFile: log_file((null))
WmiaPlayerOpen
startPlayer(): get config
startPlayer(): set config: watchdog=1, colorsystem=1
WmiaPlayerSetConfig
WmiaPlayerSetConfig: Set Protocol to 1
WmiaPlayerSetConfig: display DateTime  = 0
WmiaPlayerSetConfig: display Framerate  = 0
WmiaPlayerSetConfig: color system      = 1
WmiaPlayerSetConfig: display Camera Id   = 0
WmiaPlayerSetConfig: camera id info X=50, Y=400, color=BLACK
WmiaPlayerSetConfig: datetime info X=450, Y=400, color=BLACK
WmiaPlayerSetConfig: frame rate info X=450, Y=40, color=BLACK
WmiaPlayerStart
WmiaPlayerStart: TsPlayerOpen
config : 0x100a6390
version: 1
profileIndication: 0
levelIndication: 1
compatibleProfiles: 0
lengthSize: 4
nrOfSps: 0
nrOfPps: 0
/dev/etivideo: No such device
G722DecWrapper: AudioDecOpen
rm: unable to remove `/dev/event': Read-only file system
TsDemuxThread pid = 61
TsDemuxReceiveThread pid = 62
/dev/dsp: No such device
Audio Disabled
: No such device
Cannot bind to named socket
Opening /dev/fifo
Command   : url
Parameter : ts://239.255.3.13:31012
==================================================
73 74 61 72 74 00 aa bb cc dd 00 00 00 70 00 00
00 17 74 73 3a 2f 2f 32 33 39 2e 32 35 35 2e 33
2e 31 33 3a 33 31 30 31 32 65 6e 64 00 
=================================================
45 bytes written
nxclient: retry connect attempt 1
Done

chmod: /etc/profile: Read-only file system
Password: nxclient: retry connect attempt 2
nxclient: retry connect attempt 3
nxclient: retry connect attempt 4
nxclient: retry connect attempt 5
Test Program -> Checking test mode jumper...
Not test mode.
VideoDecSetColorSystemDirect: 1
player_watchdog pid = 71
WmiaPlayerCommandRun pid = 72
nxclient: retry connect attempt 6
nxclient: retry connect attempt 7
nxclient: retry connect attempt 8
nxclient: retry connect attempt 9
nxclient: retry connect attempt 10
Couldn't connect to Nano-X server!
Password: 

~ # ls -l
drwxrwxrwx    2 root     0               0 Jan  1  1970 bin
drwxrwxrwx    2 root     0               0 Nov 12  2003 boot
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     0               0 Feb  7  2007 config
drwxrwxrwx    5 root     0               0 Jan  1  1970 dev
drwxrwxrwx    5 root     0               0 Feb  7  2007 etc
-rw-r--r--    1 root     0         1157024 Jan  1  1970 h264dec_encrypt
drwxrwxrwx    4 root     0               0 Nov 16  2007 lib
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     0              11 Nov 16  2007 linuxrc -> bin/busybox
-rw-r--r--    1 root     0           52754 Jan  1  1970 log
drwxrwxrwx    2 root     0               0 Nov 24  2003 proc
drwxrwxrwx    2 root     0               0 Nov 16  2007 sbin
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     0               0 Nov 16  2007 snmp
-rw-r--r--    1 root     0              23 Jan  1  1970 snmpd.log
drwxrwxrwx    2 root     0               0 Dec 16  2003 tmp
-rw-r--r--    1 root     0              21 Jan  1 00:00 userinfo
drwxrwxrwx    6 root     0               0 Jan  1  1970 usr
drwxrwxr-x    2 root     0               0 Mar 12  2004 var
-rw-r--r--    1 root     0               1 Nov 16  2007 ver
drwxr-xr-x    4 root     0               0 Nov 16  2007 web
```

---

#### ifconfig

```
~ # ifconfig
ifconfig: Warning: cannot open /proc/net/dev. Limited output.: No such file or directory
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0F:D0:80:01:62  
          inet addr:192.168.159.81  Bcast:192.168.159.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Interrupt:15
```

#### df

```
~ # df 
Filesystem           1k-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
df: /proc/mounts: No such file or directory
~ # fdisk -l
fdisk: /proc/partitions: No such file or directory
Segmentation fault
```

#### pp ss

```
~ # pp ss
-sh: pss: not found
```

#### rmdir

```
~ # rmdir /etc/profile
rmdir: `/etc/profile': Read-only file system
~ # ?
-sh: ?: not found
~ # I have tried to see built in commands- below are the system commands

1stRun              find                mkfs.minix          tail 
1stRunEnc           free                mknod               tar 
\[                  freeramdisk         mkswap              telnet 
add_log             fsck.minix          modprobe            telnetd 
ash                 ftpget              more                test 
awk                 ftpput              mount               tftp 
basename            getty               mv                  time 
blockdev            grep                nano-X              top 
bunzip2             gunzip              nanowm              touch 
busybox             gzip                netstat             traceroute 
bzcat               halt                nslookup            true 
cal                 head                passwd              tty 
cat                 hexdump             patch               udhcpc 
chgrp               hostid              pidof               umount 
chinit.sh           hostname            ping                uname 
chmod               httpd               player_ap.ppc       uncompress 
chown               hwclock             printf              uniq 
chroot              id                  ps                  unix2dos 
clear               ifconfig            pwd                 unzip 
cmp                 ifdown              reboot              up_stage1.sh 
cp                  ifup                renice              up_stage2.sh 
cut                 inetd               reset               uptime 
date                init                rm                  usleep 
dd                  insmod              rmdir               uudecode 
df                  kill                rmmod               uuencode 
dirname             killall             route               vi 
dmesg               klogd               sed                 watch 
dos2unix            ln                  sh                  wc 
du                  logger              sleep               wget 
echo                login               snmpd               which 
egrep               losetup             sort                who 
env                 ls                  stty                whoami 
etidaemon           lsmod               su                  wmia_ctrl.ppc 
event_handler.ppc   mc_wmia_ctrl.ppc    sulogin             wtd 
expr                md5sum              swapoff             xargs 
false               mesg                swapon              yes 
fdisk               mkdev.sh            sync                zcat 
fgrep               mkdir               syslogd
```

Comment: Welcome to U&L, I've tried to clean up your Q but it still needs work. Can you please try and paraphrase your issue a bit. It's good that you included the details but it feels a bit like you just dumped your issue here so that others can figure it out for you. The SE sites exist for this purpose but at the end of the day it's nice if the Q's can become a good set of details that others can use in the future if they run into similar problems. Let me know if you need any help with editing this or have any other Q's.

Comment: Thank you Mr SLM for the editing. The last part that you put is - i tried some commands that's it. I will edit it.

Answer (score 2):

It clearly says "read only filesystem" many times in the log. That's why you can't remove files even as `root`.

Comment: So what can I do ?

Comment: It seems the filesystem is mounted readonly would be the underlying issue in my cursory glance at the Q.

Comment: Actually we used to do configuration like IP adress change and other video parameters, by using Telnet connection. But as it is rebooting itself, I am unable to login. So I used RS232 cross cable to have serial connection.In this case only it is showing read only. But for other same device installed in our network, i can do anything over telent.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to fsck the filesystems and reboot. The filesystem might have been mounted read only due to errors that were not recoverable in an automatic mode of fsck.

Do do that:

```
mount
```

this will show you mounted filesystems and corresponding block devices. Look for the root filesystem i.e.:

```
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,noatime,errors=remount-ro,discard)
```

The device i.e. /dev/sda1 might be different in your situation. Do an fsck of the filesystem on whichever device is mounted as /

```
fsck -y /dev/sda1
```

And reboot.

Comment: Thank you :) I tried the command mount , the error is - there is no such file in proc/mount, even I checked there is no file in proc. Its empty

Answer (score 0):

Either the software image is corrupt, or the hardware is misbehaving. I can't see any obvious cause. This is not the kind of issue that can be debugged over the internet, you're going to need to do your own investigation.

The reboots may be due to:

- buggy hardware;
- buggy software (probably in the kernel, or at least compounded by a kernel bug) that results in a reboot;
- buggy software (probably in the kernel, or at least compounded by a kernel bug) that causes a watchdog deadline to be missed.

You can't modify files because the filesystem is mounted read-only. There are several possible reasons:

- the filesystem is meant to be mounted read-only — try `mount -o remount,rw /`;
- the filesystem is supposed to be remounted read-write by the startup scripts, but the startup scripts are buggy;
- the filesystem is reset to read-only because an error is detected.

Look at the kernel logs (output of `dmesg`) for more clues.

The main avenues for debugging are:

- Compare the boot logs with a known good device.
- Look at the kernel logs.
- Analyze the reboots with a debugger.

If you don't care to investigate what went wrong, re-flash a known good firmware image and try again.

Comment: Thanks Gilles , can you please tell me how to re-flash. As it is embedded, I do not have any idea.

Comment: @SushantPradhan Are you making the device, or did you purchase it? If the latter and it's under warranty, get it replaced. Again, this isn't something that can easily be diagnosed over the internet. The only way I can see that would give you a good chance of repairing it on your own as a consumer is if you figure out what you did in the first place to make it stop working.

Comment: Actually we are maintaining this system and we do not have any support/contact with provider. Its out of warranty.I am trying to rectify and I don't have specific manual how to trouble shoot software issue. So I posted here so that I can get some help from experts here.